# Recorder PC Username Logon/Logoff

Tags: script, java, javascript, autohotkey, autorun

I need an application/script or some way to record when a user logs onto their PC, when they logoff and the users name. I would like to have it save to a .csv or a data file that I can pull together and use as a punch clock type system. Also maybe a script that something like auto hotkey can run and gather up all the times every night and save them into one overall time sheet.

Answer (score 2):

Most operating systems already do this - logging functionality for logons/logoffs is pretty standard.

In Windows the Event Log stores this information. Check out http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/understanding_windows_logging.html for deeper information.

In Linux you would look under /var/log/adm

Both could be easily used to track logon/logoffs if you want to measure time/attendance

Comment: Windows' Event Log also records Computer Locked/Unlocked events in the application log.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly what you are asking for, and it is a bit clumsy in places but this app may give you a starting point. It is written in AutoHotkey Basic and is open source so you can modify it to your needs.

> [Log Out Logger](http://crzyinc.weebly.com/log-out-logger.html) is a simple utility to monitor and record system log in
>   and shutdown times independently of Windows. Many applications show
>   system up time but most of them just read the Windows activity logs,
>   so if anything messes with those logs, like a system roll back
>   application or a system restore, then the data is lost. Log Out Logger
>   gets around this.